# Call admin export product csv from code / URL

Tags: product, csv, export

I'm looking for a way to call the magento export (System->Import/Export->Export) product export from an URL for a 3rd party system.
So I want something like 
https://my.domain.com/bla/blub/export.php?filterAttribute=2
and that shall return a csv of all products with filterAttribute 2.
I managed to do this by using dataflow export and then readfile() to the client, just to realize that this is missing lots of attributes.

So, currently I basically do something like:

```
$profile = Mage::getModel("dataflow/profile")->load($profileId);
$adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($adminUser);
$profile->load($profileId);
$guiData = $profile->getGuiData();
$guiData['product']['filter']['filterAttribute'] = 2;
$profile->setGuiData($guiData);
$profile->save();
$profile = Mage::getModel("dataflow/profile")->load($profileId);
Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
readfile($exportFile);
```

Now, how do I transfer this simple code to Import/Export?
Magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Once you know what to google for it is rather easy:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

$skipAttrs = array();

$data = array(
    "entity" => 'catalog_product',
    "file_format" => 'csv',
    "export_filter" => array(
        "seller_id" => '6'
    ),
    "skip_attr" => $skipAttrs
);

$model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
$model->setData($data);
echo $model->export();
```